# Issue receiving signals in Python/PyQt4

Tags: python, signals, pyqt4

I am working a program that should receive a signal from an external bash script (using: kill -USR1 *pid*), and update a QLabel.

In my program the label is only updated after I mouseover a 'label button'. I have created a simplified example below, as my program would be too much to look through. In the example, the signal handler function is only executed upon closing the window (if I send the USR1 signal to its pid).

Here is the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import signal

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Base(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        pid = os.getpid()
        self.main_label = QLabel("     " + str(pid) + "    ")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.main_label)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

        def signalCatcher(signum, stack):
            print "signaled!"
            self.main_label.setText("signaled!")

        signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signalCatcher)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    base = Base()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems...

1) The indenting on your `signalCatcher` function looks weird, as well as the signal connection right after it. Did you try removing the extra indent (i.e. put them in line with the other function definitions)?

2) You're missing `self` as the first parameter in your `signalCatcher` definition.

3) I think your signal connection syntax is wrong. I've had better luck putting the signal connection in the main() definition, instead of within the class itself. So instead of `signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signalCatcher)`, try putting `signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, base.signalCatcher)` right after the line `base = Base()`

So your final code should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import signal

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Base(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        pid = os.getpid()
        self.main_label = QLabel("     " + str(pid) + "    ")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.main_label)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def signalCatcher(self,signum,stack):
        print "signaled!"
        self.main_label.setText("signaled!")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    base = Base()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, base.signalCatcher)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

The signal catcher was inside of the initUI function, which I think allowed it to not need the self parameter, maybe not best practice, but I had tried it both ways.

Putting the signal connection in the main function seemed like a good thing to try but this did not help, and the sample code you provided produced the same result for me.

Did you run the code you provided? and actually have the label change when sending the USR1 signal to the process?